# How to use Paho asynchronous publication example (MQTT C Client library)

Tags: c, mqtt

An application requests for a telemetry data by sending a MQTT PUBLISH with TOPIC-A. The process as per coding https://www.eclipse.org/paho/files/mqttdoc/MQTTClient/html/subasync.html
receives the PUBLISH/TOPIC-A and should send a PUBLISH with TOPIC-B (the PAYLOAD of this msg includes the telemetry data)

target host:
Linux orangepipc2 4.19.63-sunxi64 #5.92 SMP Fri Aug 2 00:18:27 CEST 2019 aarch64 GNU/Linux
mosquitto version 1.5.7
Eclipse Paho Synchronous MQTT C Client Library Version: 1.3.1
Build level: 2019-11-06T19:07:02Z
gcc version 7.4.1 20181213 [linaro-7.4-2019.02 revision 56ec6f6b99cc167ff0c2f8e1a2eed33b1edc85d4] (Linaro GCC 7.4-2019.02)

```
int msgarrvd(void *context, char *topicName, int topicLen, MQTTClient_message *message)
{
    int i;
    char* payloadptr;
    printf("Message arrived\n");
    printf("     topic: %s\n", topicName);
    printf("   message: ");
    payloadptr = message->payload;
    for(i=0; i<message->payloadlen; i++)
    {
        putchar(*payloadptr++);
    }
    putchar('\n');
    MQTTClient_freeMessage(&message);
    MQTTClient_free(topicName);


// added code as per the main section of the example https://www.eclipse.org/paho/files/mqttdoc/MQTTClient/html/pubasync.html

    MQTTClient client1;
    MQTTClient_connectOptions conn_opts1 = MQTTClient_connectOptions_initializer;
    MQTTClient_message pubmsg = MQTTClient_message_initializer;
    MQTTClient_deliveryToken token;
    int rc1;
    MQTTClient_create(&client1, ADDRESS, CLIENTID1, MQTTCLIENT_PERSISTENCE_NONE, NULL);
    conn_opts1.keepAliveInterval = 20;
    conn_opts1.cleansession = 1;
    if ((rc1 = MQTTClient_connect(client1, &conn_opts1)) != MQTTCLIENT_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("Failed to connect, return code %d\n", rc1);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    pubmsg.payload = PAYLOAD;
    pubmsg.payloadlen = strlen(PAYLOAD);
    pubmsg.qos = QOS;
    pubmsg.retained = 0;
    MQTTClient_publishMessage(client1, TOPIC1, &pubmsg, &token);
    printf("Waiting for up to %d seconds for publication of %s\n"
            "on topic %s for client with ClientID: %s\n",
            (int)(TIMEOUT/1000), PAYLOAD, TOPIC1, CLIENTID1);
    rc1 = MQTTClient_waitForCompletion(client1, token, TIMEOUT);
    printf("Message with delivery token %d delivered\n", token);
    MQTTClient_disconnect(client1, 10000);
    MQTTClient_destroy(&client1);
//    return rc1;

// end of the added code

    return 1;
}
```

I failed in publishing the new MQTT msg with TOPIC1. Should I fork to an other process for publishing TOPIC1?

```
20191107 180109.954 3 CodeClientSub <- PINGRESP
20191107 180130.977 3 CodeClientSub -> PINGREQ (0)
20191107 180130.977 3 CodeClientSub <- PINGRESP
20191107 180136.045 3 CodeClientSub <- PUBLISH msgid: 1 qos: 1 retained: 0 payload: Hello World! blah-blah
20191107 180136.046 3 CodeClientSub -> PUBACK msgid: 1 (0)
Message arrived
     topic: MQTT_Examples
   message: Hello World! blah-blah
Failed to connect, return code -1
```

Comment: There is no need for a second MQTT client to publish the second message. Just use the existing client that you used to receive the first message.

Comment: @hardillb I agree with you. I changed my code and it worked.
To trigger the PUBLISH msg send I think a callback it would be the solution, but I do not know howto set it up. Is there someone that can help? Thank you for your support!

Comment: I found the solution using SIGNAL and KILL. I had to enlarge the scope of the data "client" and "rc" so to reuse them for the asynch function added for sending the PUBLISH msg whose payload deliver the requested telemetry data.